# react native and integrated third-party payment gateway using web view is it acceptable in the apple store?

Tags: ios, react-native

I want to develop an ios e-commerce app using react native and integrated third-party payment gateway using web view is it acceptable in the apple store?

Comment: yes. it is accepted.

Comment: It depends on what you are selling. If you are selling physical goods or services delivered outside the app then you must use an external payment gateway. If you are delivering digital goods or services in the app then you must use in app purchase.